# Disk structure error reported in Onyx but not fixable via the Disk Utility in Recovery Mode

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, recovery

On Yosemite 10.10 Onyx returns the following error:

> Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed Underlying error:
>   8: POSIX reports: Exec format error
>   The disk needs to be repaired.

I tried repairing the disk in recovery mode but the disk utility returns a message that everything is fine, however, the after running Onyx the second time the error persists.

On a related matter, the option to *repair permissions* is not available in the Disk Utility.

Comment: Same issue.  I'm keeping an eye on this one.

Comment: Out of curiosity and trying to trouble shoot for both of us, what is your current hardware? Mine: MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013) 251 GB
Flash Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.  I was able to fix it in an interesting way.

I have been testing El Capitan on an external drive.  So, I thought, why not try **Disk Utility** using OS 10.11.x and (after the second pass) it repaired the drive.  As the Beta was on a separate disk, and the Macintosh HD was unmounted at the time, it was analyzed and repaired.  Just like using a 3rd party app.

At least this was a "free" way to fix it.  Saved the hassle of reformatting and restoring.

Answer (score 2):

Disk Utility will not fix every conceivable disk corruption issue. For that you need third-party apps. I use Diskwarrior and have also had success with Drive Genius.

However there is one way to do this without buying a disk repair utility. Back up your hard drive, partition/reformat it, reinstall the OS and restore your backup. Yeah it's more complicated and a bit of a PITA but will save you money.

Comment: Thanks, I came across [similar post](http://superuser.com/questions/23478/unable-to-repair-disk-using-mac-os-x-disk-utility) and it appears that the *DW* is a highly recommended software. I was hoping that the error number `69845` would help to identify the problem precisely.

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem for me too. I booted from an external disk (USB stick in fact), ran disk utility, then Onyx found no problems.

Comment: May be worth trying, did you create [Recovery Disk Assistant](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372) on your USB?

Answer (score 0):

It because Disk Utility doesn't recognize all errors.

I had the same issue before, and I fixed it by following the instructions on the onyx's [Known Problem page](http://www.titanium.free.fr/issues.html) and this [guide](http://osxdaily.com/2013/08/07/how-to-repair-a-mac-disk-with-fsck-from-single-user-mode/) to run

```
fsck -fy
```

under Single User mode