# Invalid node structure - how to fix this?

Tags: mac, macos

[image]

I do not know how to fix this issue, did something like kext update in sngle user mode..I am searching for the one fsck command which I can do on the harddisk to fix everything...is there any?

Comment: In your screen shot it shows that the drive has Zero KB available.
That might be your problem.

Comment: Did you try the same from the Recovery partition?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194536/disk-structure-error-reported-in-onyx-but-not-fixable-via-the-disk-utility-in-re